# Is there a way to input a beta distribution on a boxplot using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a box plot where my y axis is a beta distribution created from a csv data table, while my x axis is a column from that same data table. The table is called "beta" and here is the dput for it:

```
structure(list(weld.type.ID = 1:33, weld.type = structure(c(29L, 
11L, 16L, 4L, 28L, 17L, 19L, 5L, 24L, 27L, 21L, 32L, 12L, 20L, 
26L, 25L, 3L, 7L, 13L, 22L, 33L, 1L, 9L, 10L, 18L, 15L, 31L, 
8L, 23L, 2L, 14L, 6L, 30L), .Label = c("1,40,Material A", "1,40S,Material C", 
"1,80,Material A", "1,STD,Material A", "1,XS,Material A", "10,10S,Material C", 
"10,160,Material A", "10,40,Material A", "10,40S,Material C", 
"10,80,Material A", "10,STD,Material A", "10,XS,Material A", 
"13,40,Material A", "13,40S,Material C", "13,80,Material A", 
"13,STD,Material A", "13,XS,Material A", "14,40,Material A", 
"14,STD,Material A", "14,XS,Material A", "15,STD,Material A", 
"15,XS,Material A", "2,10S,Material C", "2,160,Material A", "2,40,Material A", 
"2,40S,Material C", "2,80,Material A", "2,STD,Material A", "2,XS,Material A", 
"4,80,Material A", "4,STD,Material A", "6,STD,Material A", "6,XS,Material A"
), class = "factor"), a = c(281L, 196L, 59L, 96L, 442L, 98L, 
66L, 30L, 68L, 43L, 35L, 44L, 23L, 14L, 24L, 38L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 
19L, 37L, 38L, 6L, 11L, 29L, 6L, 16L, 6L, 16L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 12L
), b = c(7194L, 4298L, 3457L, 2982L, 4280L, 3605L, 2229L, 1744L, 
2234L, 1012L, 1096L, 1023L, 1461L, 1303L, 531L, 233L, 630L, 502L, 
328L, 509L, 629L, 554L, 358L, 501L, 422L, 566L, 403L, 211L, 159L, 
268L, 167L, 140L, 621L)), row.names = c(NA, -33L), class = "data.frame")
```

The first code I tried was:

```
SampleValuesBox <- rbeta(10000,beta$a,beta$b)
SampleValuesBoxPlot <- data.frame(yvalue = SampleValuesBox)

my_boxplot <- ggplot(beta, aes(x = weld.type.ID, y = yvalue)) + 
  geom_boxplot()+
  labs(x="Weld Type ID", y="repair rate")

print(my_boxplot)
```

I got this error

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'yvalue' not found

Second code I tried was:

```
SampleValuesBox <- rbeta(10000,beta$a,beta$b)
ggplot(data.frame(vals=SampleValuesBox))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = beta$weld.type.ID, y = vals))+
  labs(x="Weld Type ID", y="repair rate")
```

I got this error

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data
>   (10000): x

Third code I tried:

```
my_boxplot <- ggplot(beta, aes(x = weld.type.ID, y = SampleValuesBox)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  labs(x="Weld Type ID", y="repair rate")
```

I got this error

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data
>   (33): y

The expected outcome is a plot that looks like this:

[image: Expected outcome]

I can't seem to find a way around combining a beta distribution with a column from my "beta" data table into the same box plot. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I ran `droplevels()` on your sample data, which gets rid of unused categorical levels (categories that are in the full data, but not in this sample). That should make your question a little more approachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Life (as far as ggplot2 is concerned) will be easier if you put all the needed data fields into a single data frame, & pass that into `ggplot()`. See if the following works for you:

```
# specify number of desired yvalues for each weld.type.ID
n <- 100 

# generate yvalues from beta distribution for each weld.type.ID
SampleValuesBox <- lapply(seq(1, nrow(beta)),
                          function(i) rbeta(n, beta$a[i], beta$b[i]))

# combine generated yvalues with their associated weld.type.ID values
SampleValuesBoxPlot <- data.frame(weld.type.ID = rep(beta$weld.type.ID, each = n),
                                  yvalue = unlist(SampleValuesBox))

ggplot(SampleValuesBoxPlot, 
       aes(x = factor(weld.type.ID), y = yvalue)) + 
  geom_boxplot()+
  labs(x="Weld Type ID", y="repair rate")
```

[image: plot]